# Particular integral trial solution with repeated roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the DE $y''+6y'+9y=x^3e^{4x}$, I'm confused what my trial solution should be for the particular integral. I know that if the RHS is $P_n(x)e^{\lambda x}$ and $m_1, m_2$ solution of the characteristic equation, then the trial solution is normally $x^kQ_n(x)e^{\lambda x}$, where:

$k=0$ if $m_1 \neq m_2 \neq \lambda$

$k=1$ if $m_1 \neq m_2 = \lambda$

and $k=2$ if $m_1=m_2=\lambda$.

But my situation is the case $m_1=m_2 \neq \lambda$.

Intuitively I feel like I should try $Q_{n+1}(x)e^{\lambda x}$, but I have no idea if this is correct - or, if it is, why.

Comment: You sure that $m_1=m_2$ ?

Comment: @Isham, whoops, I wrote down the question wrong! It's fixed.

Comment: Well then it has nothing to do with your $\lambda (=4)$ so no neeed to multiply by x the particular solution...You only care when the homogeneous has the same value as your $\lambda$

Answer (score 1):

$$y''+9y'+9y=x^3e^{4x}$$
We know $m^2+9m+9=0$ gives 
$$m_{1,2}=\dfrac{-9\pm3\sqrt5}{2}$$
so we have $m_1\neq m_2$. Then Let
$$y_p=(Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D)e^{4x}$$

Comment: Thanks, although I'm terribly sorry I wrote down the equation wrong - I've edited it now. It should be that $m_1=m_2=3$.

Comment: In this case, $4$ is not the root of characteristic equation, then the answer remains the same!

Comment: Your equation now has $m_1=m_2=-3$, not what you wanted, but still not the factor in the exponential on the right.